# List of Lists using DAO in Java

Tags: java, dao

I have 3 differents DAO to gain access to a database.

First DAO query :

```
private String SELECT_CONTRACT_NUMBER = "SELECT branch, contract, endorsement FROM contract";
```

Second DAO query :

```
private static final String SELECT_PROJECT_ID = "SELECT projectid FROM project WHERE branch = ? AND contract = ? AND endorsement = ?";
```

Third DAO query :

```
private String SELECT_SINISTER = " SELECT start_date, end_date FROM sinister WHERE branch = ? AND projectid = ? AND endorsement = 0";
```

Each DAO have a public method to return the results, let's name them getContract(), getProject(String branchId, int contractId, int endorsementNb) and getSinisterDate(String branchId, int projectId).

In my application I'm trying to have a List of Lists to collect all datas by contract

I'm stuck on something like this :

```
// In the first List I'm collecting all contract
    List<Contract> listContractA = ContractDao.getContract();

// Then I'm using the results of the first list to collect the ProjectId of each contracts
    for (Contract contract: listContractA ) {
        List<Project> listProject = ProjectDao.getProjectId(
                contract.getBranchId(),
                contract.getContractNb(),
                contract.getEndorsementNb());
    }

// The third list collect all sinisters date
    for (Project project: listProject ) {
        List<SinisterDate> listSinisterDate = SinisterDateDao.getSinisterDate(
                project.getBranchId(),
                project.getProjectId());
    }
```

Is doing it that way is a good method to have all datas in the last list?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my post with my question

Comment: I think it is not a good idea to have a loop calling the DB, because that is basically a N+1 problem and bad for performance. Rather build a query that joins the data as needed at the DB level.

Comment: Actually this was my first thought but having all queries separated is a specific request for the application.

Comment: That's an interesting request... The solution you show in your question does not only require a lot of unnecessary disk access, but also introduces the risk of race conditions.